# How to convert <br>'s to (un)ordered list in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array which is coming from db. Array has strings which is delimited by `<br>`. So I want to explode them and convert it to a

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

structure using a function (`listIt($list)`):

```
function listIt($list)
{
  $list = mb_convert_case($list, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
  $text = explode('<br>', $list);
  $menu = '<ul>';

  foreach ($text as $li)
  {
    $menu .= '<li>' .   $li . '</li>';
  }

  return $menu . '</ul>';
}
```

My Array (`rawMenu`) is the following:

```
 array (size=5)
  0 => string 'Banana<br>Cheese<br>Egg<br>Salad<br>Water<br>Juice<br>Coffee' (length=62)
  1 => string 'Soup<br>Potato<br>Chicken<br>Fish<br>Juice<br>Wine<br>Salad' (length=61)
  2 => string 'Banana<br>Cheese<br>Egg<br>Salad<br>Water<br>Juice<br>Coffee' (length=62)
  3 => string 'Soup<br>Potato<br>Chicken<br>Fish<br>Juice<br>Wine<br>Salad' (length=61)
  4 => string 'Banana<br>Cheese<br>Egg<br>Salad<br>Water<br>Juice<br>Coffee' (length=62)
```

The problem is string which I pass to `listIt($rawMenu[4])` function returns:

```
<ul>
   <li>Banana<br>Cheese<br>Egg<br>Salad<br>Water<br>Juice<br>Coffee</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `MB_CASE_TITLE` converts the first letter to upper case (`<Br>`), then you have to split on `Br`:

```
$st = 'Banana<br>Cheese<br>Egg<br>Salad<br>Water<br>Juice<br>Coffee';
$list = mb_convert_case($st, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
$text = explode('<Br>', $list);

$menu = '<ul>';
foreach ($text as $li){
  $menu .= '<li>' .   $li . '</li>';
}
$menu .= '</ul>';

print_r($menu);
```

Outputs:

```
<ul><li>Banana</li><li>Cheese</li><li>Egg</li><li>Salad</li><li>Water</li><li>Juice</li><li>Coffee</li></ul>
```

Working example in sandbox [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d99de649cf27ba7e71bfe0256e911eaaa66fe341).

As noted in the comments by @LightnessRacesinOrbit good practice would be to swap explode and conversion:

```
$st = 'Banana<br>Cheese<br>Egg<br>Salad<br>Water<br>Juice<br>Coffee';
$text = explode('<br>', $st);

$menu = '<ul>';
foreach ($text as $li){
  $menu .= '<li>' .   $li . '</li>';
}
$menu .= '</ul>';
$menu = mb_convert_case($menu, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');

print_r($menu);
```

Comment: Erm I would instead swap the explosion and the case conversion around.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I would too actually.

Comment: I'm also curious as to the introduction of `(` and `)` around the call to `explode`.

Comment: That was a typo, I was outputting the exploded array in the sandbox.